# Configure nginx to serve static files

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine, file-server, static-content

I'm trying to serve static files(HTMLs, JS and CSS) from a Google compute engine instance running Debian 8.
I used git to clone the web app to the folder `/var/www/prod/app` with command

```
sudo git clone <my repo>
```

I made a conf file in sites-enabled folder `app.conf`. Here's the content

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/prod/app;
    location / {
    }
}
```

Isn't this config enough to make my machine serve the files when I type my machine's ip address/path ?

I see the `welcome to nginx` page when I type my instance's ip address in browser. But none of the files in prod/app are served. I get 404 for all the paths I try.  Could someone help me configure this.

Comment: Try adding a "server_name example.com" and restarting Nginx. I'm not sure you even need that location. If that doesn't work please edit your question to include the full Nginx config, all site configurations, a curl (showing command line and the start of the output), and the matching Nginx access/error log line (not the whole log). I suspect someone else will spot the problem quickly though.

Comment: Its a fresh installation of nginx, other than my conf file, there are only default ones in the system. Its a newly created Debian instance. Only installatoins are Git and Nginx.

Comment: Disable default config

Comment: "The default config" could be many things depending on the distribution. That is why it is important to have the full configuration here in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Hint: Please check if you have exposed your .git folder with your website (www.example.com/.git). The way you described let me assume that.

Comment: I figured it out. The `default` config in sites-enabled forlder had a server block that would override my config. Commented it out and things are working as expected. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Consider posting self-answer with the solution so that other user's with the similar issue can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Nginx has a default config file (without the extension ".conf") in the following path

> ```
> /etc/nginx/sites-enable/default
> ```

The default config has a server block for `default_server` that serves the folder `/var/www/html`. This would override any config I made for serving static files without a `server_name` field.

I commented out these lines and things are working as expected.

Thanks to Alexy Ten and Tero Kilkaken for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `try_files` inside location and make it the default server:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/prod/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Then you need to restart the nginx service.